# MySQL Upsert with Insert Only Column Value

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is it possible to do an upsert but only set a column value on insert (and not set the column value on update).

For example, for a createdBy column, we only want to set the value on insert, we don't want to override that value on update (because we lose who originally inserted the column).

Note that we only know the currently logged in user. So updatedBy is simple -- always use the value of the logged in user. But createdBy is hard. Use the value of the logged in user but only for an insert -- don't override this on update.

Example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `createdBy` NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `updatedBy` NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX (`name`)
);
```

Example of a standard upsert:

```
INSERT INTO `movie` (`name`, `createdBy`, `updatedBy`)
  VALUES ('The Matrix', 'Jill', 'Jill') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`),
  `name` = VALUES(`name`),
  `createdBy` = VALUES(`createdBy`),
  `updatedBy` = VALUES(`updatedBy`)
;
```

Here's my attempt to only set the createdBy column on insert using IFNULL. But this doesn't work and results in createdBy always being null.

```
INSERT INTO `movie` (`name`, `createdBy`, `updatedBy`) 
  VALUES ('The Matrix', IFNULL(`createdBy`, 'Jill'), 'Jill') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`),
  `name` = VALUES(`name`),
  `createdBy` = VALUES(`createdBy`),
  `updatedBy` = VALUES(`updatedBy`)
;
```

Results wanted:

Case 1: Jill runs an upsert that inserts a row.

```
id = 1
name = 'The Matrix'
createdBy = 'Jill' // Created by Jill
updatedBy = 'Jill' // Last updated by Jill
```

Case 2: Bob runs an upsert that updates the same row.

```
id = 1
name = 'The Matrix Reloaded'
createdBy = 'Jill' // Created by Jill (do not change value on update)
updatedBy = 'Bob' // Last updated by Bob
```

Comment: please provide your table definition, since  at a first glance an upsert per ser does not make any sense, im aiming to always insert if a condition is true. It is not clear based on your question if you want to update the createdby column OR insert a new record.

Comment: Question updated with schema and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle guessing that Name is the Key, feel free to give it a try [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/063e24/1).

This is the basic syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `movie` (`name`, `UpdatedBy`,`CreatedBy`)
  VALUES ('Star wars', 'NameA','NameB')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `UpdatedBy` = VALUES(`UpdatedBy`)
;
```

**Notice**: NameA and NameB can be the same so you dont get nulls on inserts

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't know why this works but it does!

Comment: This took me a while to finally understand this. I never appreciated that this statement has two parts insert + update. So we can insert specific columns + update (if exists) different columns. I always thought both sets of columns had to be the same.

Comment: yes exactly really simple

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `movie` (`name`, `createdBy`)
  VALUES ('The Matrix', 'Jill')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`)
;
```

Comment: This works and is the same approach as the accepted answer.